# Is there any function like 'initmesh' in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave

I am learning to generate meshes in Octave for a given geometric domain. Unlike MATLAB, where 'initmesh' requires a geometric domain 'g', I am unable to find such type of function in Octave.

I am working with 'delaunay', which is great for Rectangular type domains. It would be really helpful if you could demonstrate meshing in L domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options are the [msh package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/msh/index.html)/[gmsh](https://gmsh.info/) or [distmesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/).

An example of msh is [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/msh/function/msh2m_gmsh.html). You need to make sure that you have gmsh available in octave to get that working.

Using distmesh, I created a mesh for an L domain using this command:

```
>> pv = [0 0; 3 0; 3 1; 1 1; 1 4; 0 4; 0 0];
>> [p,t]=distmesh2d(@dpoly,@huniform,0.2,[-1,-1; 5,5],pv,pv);
```

[image: L domain]

distmesh involves some c++ code and thus platform dependent libraries. There is a slower, pure matlab variant [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/distmesh/distmesh.html) where you can the matlab implementation of the dsegment function for this.